# rosnode ping error

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to all,

I am trying to follow the tutorials on ROS wiki.

I came across an error concerning the rosnode ping command.

I am getting the following error:

root@ubuntu:~# rosnode ping my_turtle
rosnode: node is [/my_turtle]
pinging /my_turtle with a timeout of 3.0s
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rosnode", line 35, in 
rosnode.rosnodemain()
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode.py", line 713, in rosnodemain
sys.exit(_rosnode_cmd_ping(argv) or 0)
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode.py", line 681, in _rosnode_cmd_ping
rosnode_ping(node_name, verbose=True, max_count=options.ping_count)
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode.py", line 292, in rosnode_ping
errnum, msg = e
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
root@ubuntu:~#

Any clues?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27920/rosnode-ping-error/) by [cg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1801/cg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-19**:
Sorry, I have no clue, but it usually helps people if you tell them what version Ubuntu and ROS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks Kevin,

I had finally worked it out, my localhost was pointing to a static IP I had set in the past, that was different than the one I needed.

I changed the IP settings and it worked.

Regards,

cg

---

Originally posted by [cg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1801/cg/) with karma: 36 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2